# Dryscrape "Can Not Find XVFB" Error on Nginx & Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: python, linux, nginx, web-scraping, server

I need a help about Dryscrape and XVFB. I'm using Dryscrape on my Flask application for web scraping from a javascript page. If I serve it with `python3 main.py` and the app config `app.run(host="0.0.0.0")` everything works great at port 5000. But I have to use Nginx and uWSGI to serve my application on a domain. So, while I'm serving the app with Nginx, I get this error.

```
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:   File "./scrape_manager.py", line 10, in get_details
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:     dryscrape.start_xvfb()
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:   File "/home/user/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dryscrape/xvfb.py", line 8, in start_xvfb
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:     xvfb = Xvfb()
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:   File "/home/user/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xvfbwrapper.py", line 41, in __init__
Sep 30 19:39:16 /address\ uwsgi[959]:     raise EnvironmentError(msg)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was in the service file of Nginx.

app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/app/app
Environment="PATH=/home/user/app/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/app/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/user/app/app/app.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Actually the source of failure was the environment path, it's only one and it's the virtual environment of the application. But Dryscrape needs to access XVFB from /bin or /usr/bin (check it, where does it exist). In this way, I had to extend environment paths with both to try and I added `/usr/bin` and `/bin`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/app/app
Environment="PATH=/home/user/app/venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/app/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/user/app/app/app.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the correct service file but one of them (`/bin` or `/usr/bin`) is may be unnecessary so you have to check the paths, where XVFB file executing from. If not sure, add /usr/bin and /bin too; it'll work but if you are able to find the path, add only one like this below.

```
Environment="PATH=/home/user/app/venv/bin:/usr/bin"
```

And also this status might be a tricky related to your user-group / user permissions too.